# Problema con el backdrop del modal de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un problema al cerrar un modal, este problema no siempre ocurre, bueno el detalle esta que se queda el `backdrop` del modal les adjunto imagen.

[image: Backdrop del modal]

Se cierra el modal pero el `backdrop` permanece, a forma en que lo estoy cerrando es de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#Agregar').formValidation({
    opciones..
}).on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/VistaPopUp/modalAgregar",
        data: $("#Agregar").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            Exito(data);
            $('#ModalAgregar').modal('hide');
        },//mostramos el mensaje de error o exito dependiendo del caso
        error: Error1
    });
});
```

Después de enviar el formulario me devuelve un Json con texto de que si se valido la inserción o caso contrario el error, este texto lo adjunto a un mensaje de alerta para el cual uso [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) los muestro y después cierro el modal.

> Como les mencione arriba aveces se cierra correctamente y a veces se
>   queda el `backdrop`.

Ya intente cambiando la forma de cerrar el modal con `$('#ModalAgregar').modal('hide');` y sigue produciendo lo mismo después de varios intentos.

Así esta definido mi modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close fui-cross" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-primary">Agregar Cita</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="Agregar" role="form" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <input name="Tipo" type="hidden" id="Tipo" />
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input id="titulo" name="Descripcion" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="*Título:" style="border: none; width: 100%;" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="margin: 5px; border-top: 2px solid #e1ebe9" />
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <textarea name="Notas_Inicio" placeholder="Notas:" class="form-control" rows="2" style="border: none; resize: none;" onkeypress="return hashtag(event);"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <label class="text-primary" style="float: left;">*Datos requeridos</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yo he arreglado esto de 2 maneras:

Una es quitar la clase `fade` de el modal en tu `<div>` principal

Y la segunda es forzar q el backdrop se quite despues de tu success handler

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

**Por peticion del OP** y aplicar el código únicamente si se quedaba visible el `backdrop`

```
...
$('#ModalAgregar').modal('hide');
if ($('.modal-backdrop').is(':visible')) {
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); 
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); 
};
...
```

Comment: No se me ocurrió hacer esto de tanta desesperacion de solucionarlo lo deje de la siguiente manera
 if ($('.modal-backdrop').is(":visible")) {$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                } ; debido a que no siempre aparece por eso lo dece encerrado en un div Gracias por hacerme recurrir a algo basico

Comment: Muchas rojobo, me funciono a la perfección! Saludos!

Comment: @rojobo : Agradezco el aporte me fue muy útil. no se me había presentado este problema que se quedara el backdrop , utilice las dos primeras lineas después del sucess , en mi caso atenúa el backdrop muestra un sweetalert y una vez que cierro el sweetalert se elimina por completo el backdrop sin tener que refrescar la pantalla.

Answer (score 4):

La solución es colocar en el botón de la acción esto: `data-backdrop="false"` y `data-dismiss="modal"`

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger danger" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">Action</button>
```

Porque si lo haces como lo planteas, cuando vuelve a llamar al modal, no se te desplegará porque fue removido.

Comment: Tu solución ya la había intentado, pero como indico en la pregunta, seguía manteniendo el `backdrop` visible, entonces digamos que eliminar el `backdrop` fue una solución forzosa, y ya que dices _cuando vuelve a llamar al modal, no se te desplegará porque fue removido._ de hecho no, el js de bootstrap remueve o elimina el `backdrop` por lo tanto al volver a llamar al modal este volverá a ser agregado al DOM.