# Cerrar Modal Popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un modal popup que se cierra al seleccionar un elemento de una tabla.

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El popup se cierra, pero al hacerlo deja bloqueada mi plantilla `html`.

¿por qué sucede esto?

Este es el código que uso para cerrar el popup:

```
    $(document).ready(iniciar);

function iniciar() {
    $("#busqueda_parroquia tr td").click(clickTabla);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#busqueda_parroquia').DataTable();
    var dato = "";
    //para seleccionar una opcion
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            dato = "";
            console.log(dato);
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            dato = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
            console.log(dato);
        }
    });
});

$("#BusquedaParroquia").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var renglon = $(this);
    var campo1, campo2, campo3;
    $(this).children("td").each(function (i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                campo1 = $(this).text();
                break;
            case 1:
                campo2 = $(this).text();
                break;
            case 2:
                campo3 = $(this).text();
                break;
        }
    })
    $("#txt_codigo").val(campo1);
    $("#txt_nombre").val(campo2);
    if (campo3 == "A") {
        $("#che_estado").prop("checked", "checked");
    }
    CierraPopup();
});

function CierraPopup() {
    $("#popupBusquedaParroquia").modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');//eliminamos la clase del body para poder hacer scroll
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();//eliminamos el backdrop del modal
}
```

Modal

```
 <!-- Modal Escenario-->
<div class="modal fade" id="popupBusquedaParroquia" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Busqueda de Parroquias</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="BusquedaParroquia" class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="stock_bodega">Busqueda por:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%" id="stock_bodega">
                            <option>Nombre</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="texto_buscar">Texto a Buscar:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="texto_buscar">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="dataTables_scrollBody">
                        <table style="width: 100%;" id="busqueda_parroquia" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>001</td>
                                  <td>La Troncal</td>
                                  <td>A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>002</td>
                                  <td>San Joose</td>
                                  <td>A</td>
                                </tr>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- Modal Escenario-->
```

Comment: Relacionado http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/11201/6635

Comment: que es lo que hace exactamente esta parte? `$(document).ready(iniciar);function iniciar() {    $("#busqueda_parroquia tr td").click(clickTabla);}`

Comment: que la función esta iniciada para que pueda detectar el click que hace el usuario sobre la tabla.

Comment: esa funcion es la del problema

Comment: solo es una función de mas, no es necesaria ya que tienes esta `$("#BusquedaParroquia").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {` que es la que detecta el clic, no necesitas inicializar alguna función ya que estas se inician en cuanto sucede el evento del clic

Comment: @JuankGlezz ese era el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hola @RicardoEspaña Si se ha solucionado este problema no dudes en aceptarla en ✔ debajo de los votos, así ganas puntos de reputación, si te es útil una pregunta y/o respuesta no dudes en votar ayudas al crecimiento de la pagina como del usuario

Comment: haz lo mismo con tus preguntas anteriores. Saludos :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Respuesta obtenida de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/11202/6635

Una solución como lo sugiere la respuesta antes mencionada quitar la clase `fade` del modal o bien hacer lo que haces tu, una eliminación manual de clases

Ahora si nos acoplamos a tu código esto seria una solución.

Si aun aplicando tu función `CerrarPopup()` deja bloqueada tu plantilla es porque aun hace falta eliminar la clase `modal-open` del `body`

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

Por lo tanto tu función quedaría de esta forma:

```
function CierraPopup() {
  $("#popupBusquedaParroquia").modal('hide');//ocultamos el modal
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');//eliminamos la clase del body para poder hacer scroll
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();//eliminamos el backdrop del modal
}
```

**Edit:**

Estas iniciando un clic cuando no es necesario, ya que esto se vuelve código de más y puede generar errores o mal funcionamiento. Por lo tanto es mejor quitarlo

```
$(document).ready(iniciar);

function iniciar() {
    $("#busqueda_parroquia tr td").click(clickTabla);
}
```

Comment: al parecer el error es otro no me funciona puedo añadir el código donde hago la selección de un elemento de la tabla y la cargo en el textbox, tal vez ese código sea el del problema

Comment: @RicardoEspaña añade todo el código necesario para poder reproducir el problema, editando tu pregunta

Comment: ya añadí las funciones

Answer (score 5):

La manera que estás escondiendo el modal no es correcta. Lo que haces es esconder el html del div que contiene el modal y después eliminar el html del `.modal-backdrop`. Se deberían usar las funciones javascript que boostrap ofrece.

Según la [documentación oficial de bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), los métodos para mostrar y esconder modals son:

Mostrar modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Esconder modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Para esconder el modal, si previamente has hecho un `show` solo deberías tener que llamar al `hide`.

Comment: si lo esconde de esta manera pero porque la plantilla queda bloqueada ese es mi problema igual realice el cambio de esconder el popup de la manera que tu dices.

Comment: Sin más datos es complicado saber que puede ser lo que pasa. Hay algún error de consola, alguna id repetida...?

Comment: añadi una imagen a la pregunta tal vez sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Entiendo que si utiliza bootstrap, la clase 'modal-backdrop' es propia de bootstrap y ahora con la imagen que ha añadido, se ve la estructura de un modal de bootrstap. Aun así, creo que la respuesta de @JuankGlezz puede ser útil.

Answer (score 3):

Estimado para que no tenga que quitar clases deje que la misma modal se encargue de eso. Le recominedo coloque este código en su aplicación. Para la parte del Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(iniciar);

function iniciar() {
$("#busqueda_parroquia tr td").click(clickTabla);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#busqueda_parroquia').DataTable();
var dato = "";
//para seleccionar una opcion
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        dato = "";
        console.log(dato);
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        dato = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
        console.log(dato);
    }
});
});

$("#BusquedaParroquia").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var renglon = $(this);
var campo1, campo2, campo3;
$(this).children("td").each(function (i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            campo1 = $(this).text();
            break;
        case 1:
            campo2 = $(this).text();
            break;
        case 2:
            campo3 = $(this).text();
            break;
    }
})
$("#txt_codigo").val(campo1);
$("#txt_nombre").val(campo2);
if (campo3 == "A") {
    $("#che_estado").prop("checked", "checked");
}
CierraPopup();
});

function CierraPopup() {
$('#cerrar').click(); //Esto simula un click sobre el botón close de la modal, por lo que no se debe preocupar por qué clases agregar o qué clases sacar.
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();//eliminamos el backdrop del modal
}
```

Para la parte de su modal lo único que tiene que hacer es darle un id al botón de cerrar. Una cosa así:

```
<!-- Modal Escenario-->
<div class="modal fade" id="popupBusquedaParroquia" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Busqueda de Parroquias</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="BusquedaParroquia" class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="stock_bodega">Busqueda por:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%" id="stock_bodega">
                        <option>Nombre</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="texto_buscar">Texto a Buscar:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="texto_buscar">
                </div>
                <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="dataTables_scrollBody">
                    <table style="width: 100%;" id="busqueda_parroquia" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Codigo</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>001</td>
                              <td>La Troncal</td>
                              <td>A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>002</td>
                              <td>San Joose</td>
                              <td>A</td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="cerrar">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>  <!-- Modal Escenario-->
```

Espero haberle ayudado en su proyecto. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes simplemente eliminarlo, por ejemplo así:

$('.fade').remove();

$('body').removeClass('modal-open');

Answer (score 2):

```
$("mymodal").modal("toggle");
```

esto es como un switch si el modal esta en show actua el hide y viceversa

Answer (score -1):

A mi me funciono invocando `$('#myModal').modal('show')` mediante un `onclick()` desde mi boton nuevo y cerre invocando una funcion ocultar_modal() `{$('#myModal').modal('hide')}`

Answer (score -2):

Me funciono con $('.modal').removeClass('shw');
$('modal-backdrop').remove();